# How I can report Ubuntu about issues in new Ubuntu version 13.04-64

Tags: 13.04

I am using ubuntu since 11.04. The newest version 13.04 blockades the use with many issues. I want to tell them all to get a better useful ubuntu version in the future. Is this side the right one? 
For example some new installed aplications are not starting. Or about the new changes, how useful they are

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should file bug reports, see [Instructions on filing a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

You can report bugs on https://launchpad.net to a specific project, but this is to new or unexperienced users a bit complicated and requires some time. So if this does not suit you, there is also something everyone can do.

When an application crashes and Ubuntu asks for a **bug report**, just **allow** to send it. This will also give some technical information to the developers without making you trouble to collect them. I know sometimes it's annoying, but on the long term it will help. This is something just everyone can do to help, no matter how technically savvy they are.

If you can afford it, of course doing both is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you report the specifics of your problem to https://launchpad.net ?

This will help all of us get a better Ubuntu. Thanks.

:)